# "The Queen and the Duke of Edinburgh would like to be remembered to you." - what does that mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar, british-english, phrase-meaning, quotes

What does "would like to be remembered to you" mean in the statement: ""The Queen and the Duke of Edinburgh would like to be remembered to you." ?

This was later released by the Royal Household to a member of the public who was injured in the accident also involving Prince Philip's vehicle.

I should point out that my question is:

- not to pass judgement or assign fault to any party in the accident
- not to pass judgement on a person's fitness to drive or required use safety facilities whilst driving
- not to debate the need for the Royal Family. From a personal perspective I'm not opposed to them. Sources elsewhere on the internet can do a much better job than myself to point out how the UK benefits from having a Royal Family.

My question is:

- To understand the meaning of the phrase: "would like to be remembered to you.".

I'm not the only one to observe the peculiar grammar as well to not understand what the message was saying. You'll find articles on this but I've not found one that disects the meaning, hence posting the question here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remember) gives one meaning of **remember** as

> 1.3 (remember someone to) Convey greetings from one person to (another).

So the sentence

> The Queen and the Duke of Edinburgh would like to be remembered to you.

means

> The Queen and the Duke of Edinburgh would like convey their greetings.

This seems quite a stilted and formal statement, but this is royal protocol.

Comment: Good point: "This seems quite a stilted and formal statement, but this is royal protocol." - the sentiment of the response is worthy of debate in politics.stackexchange.com But I won't go there.

Comment: "Give my regards to Broadway / Remember me to Herald Square ..." Americans will use it, too, if the meter fits.

Comment: It may be more than just protocol (though that's just a guess, right?) In the UK, admitting responsibility after a car accident - such as by apologising - means your insurance company is off the hook for the bill. Bit of a moot point, perhaps, when your wife owns the country and you're worth £30m in your own right, but the Windsor clan are notoriously penny-pinching... in the frugal sense, and in others.

Comment: It's not unusual to say "Remember me to John", meaning something like "When you see John, tell him that you recently saw me and that I'm thinking kindly of him."

Answer (score 1):

It is so unfortunate that ***“remember me to ___”*** is going out of fashion. It is such a good way of saying

> Let ——- know that I say hello.

In fact, it means more than just "hello", it’s fonder with a hint of respect. It sounds very formal but many times I’ve heard this colloquially used in Nottinghamshire growing up. Very pleasant to the ear.

Comment: I’d certainly rather be remembered to someone than dismembered by someone.